# matplotlib.figure.suptitle(), what does 'sup' stand for?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I understand that `matplotlib.figure.suptitle()` adds a title to a figure.

But what does the "sup" stand for?

Comment: A "Super" title. A title which is at the top of the figure above *all* subplots

Comment: The suggested duplicate does explain the difference between title and suptitle, but not what "sup" stands for, which is what the OP asked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is an abbreviation indicating a "super" title. It is a title which appears at the top of the figure, whereas a normal `title` only appears above a particular `axes`. If you only have one `axes` object, then there's unlikely an appreciable difference, but the difference happens when you have multiple subplots on the same `figure` and you would like a title at the top of the figure *not* on each of the `axes` objects.

Comment: A suptitle appears to be placed slightly higher above the top of the chart than a title.